# How to get the split values of top important variables on each tree by random forest in R?

Tags: r, random-forest

The general idea is that I'd like to find out the top important variables from a random forest model and get the split values of these variables on each tree. Then I could get the mean split value for each variable and hopefully figure out how they relate to the final decision of the model (as y=1 or y=0).

So I generated a dataset as below:

```
set.seed(123)
mydata<-data.frame(y=rbinom(500, 1, 0.5),
                   x0=rbinom(500, 1, 0.5),
                   x1=rbinom(500, 1, 0.5),
                   x2=rnorm(500, mean = 54, sd=9.8),
                   x3=rnorm(500, mean = 45, sd=20),
                   x4=rnorm(500, mean = 8.3, sd=0.6),
                   x5=rnorm(500, mean = 540, sd=200),
                   x6=rnorm(500, mean = 1500, sd=585),
                   x7=rnorm(500, mean = 7, sd=4.5),
                   x8=rnorm(500, mean = 9.7, sd=1.7),
                   x9=rnorm(500, mean = 18.3, sd=3.1),
                   x10=rnorm(500, mean = 3.2, sd=0.2),
                   x11=rnorm(500, mean = 33, sd=13.3),
                   x12=rnorm(500, mean = 1.5, sd=0.6),
                   x13=floor(runif(500, min=-1, max=4)),
                   x14=floor(runif(500, min=-1, max=2)),
                   x15=floor(runif(500, min=-1, max=3))
                   )
cols<-c("y","x0","x1","x13","x14","x15")
mydata[cols] <- lapply(mydata[cols], factor)
```

Then I performed the random forest model:

```
library(randomForest)
set.seed(123)
fit <- randomForest(y ~ ., data=mydata, mtry=4, importance=TRUE, proximity=TRUE,
                    keep.forest=TRUE,replace=FALSE,keep.inbag=TRUE)
```

And then I chose the top 5 important variables as below:

```
importance<-data.frame(importance(fit))
head(importance)
importance_sort <- importance[order(importance$MeanDecreaseAccuracy, decreasing = TRUE), ]
importance_sort[1:5,]
```

The top 5 variables selected were x4, x8, x5, x1 and x13.

Also I could find the split values from:

```
fit$forest$xbestsplit
```

My question is how to find the split values of x4, x8, x5, x1 and x13 from `fit$forest$xbestsplit`?
Or is there any easier way to get it?